# Ruby: What are the ways to handle a .txt file as template?

Tags: ruby, text-manipulation

I got the following template:

```
|Info1|Info2|Info3|Info4|Info5|Info6|Info7|Info8|Info9|Info10|
|Info11|Info12|Info13|Info14|Info15|Info16|Info17|Info18|Info19|Info20|
```

And I have to substitute each information with real data and put it into a .txt file, what could be a good way to handle this in Ruby?

Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place this in a file called `subtemplate.rb`:

```
subs = { 'Info1' => "Hello", 'Info2' => 'World' }

STDIN.each do |line|
    puts line.gsub(/\w+/) { |m| subs[m] }
end
```

Run from the command line:

```
 ruby subtemplate.rb < template.txt > output.txt
```

where `template.txt` contains the template file. Then `output.txt` is

```
|Hello|World|||||||||
|||||||||||
```

Comment: +1 but might want to use `/\b\w+\b/` so `Info1` doesn't clobber `Info10`.

Comment: @maerics `\w+` is a "greedy" match; it will consume all available `\w` characters. As you can see from this example, it did not match `Info10`.

Comment: I know It's a bad way to handle templates, but It's the way a federal institution here in Brazil requires me to send them information via its webservice :facepalm: